# What is the minimum interval to execute the function “scheduledJob”?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, dolphindb

What is the minimum interval to execute the function “scheduledJob”?

What is the minimum interval to execute a scheduled job? Is it 10 minutes? Or 20 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till the 1.30.13 version, DolphinDB’s minimum execution time interval is 5 minutes for single scheduled task (the scheduleJob)
If you want to perform some timed tasks below this frequency, you can set up multiple timed tasks, and then stagger the execution time.